# What is wrong with my DNS set up?

Tags: domain-name-system, apache-2.4, linode, redirection, 1and1

Ok so I'm running a server on Linode (Ubuntu 14.04, Apache2) I am redirecting the domain from 1and1.com to Linode(Linked to Linode's nameservers) via HTTP redirection to the IP of my server. (http://255.255.255.255)

On the Linode side, I have the domain zone set in this format: domain.com And the reverse DNS is connecting to both IPv4 and IPv6.

All seems to be connecting and working great, however.. the website will run on any device on my network PERFECTLY. But, whenever I send the link to a device outside of my network, I get this error: Firefox has detected that the server is redirecting the request for this address in a way that will never complete.

I have tested it on multiple browsers/devices/operating systems and it's always the same outcome. (mind you, the error is worded differently in each browser.)

What do I need to do to fix this?

Also, sorry I didn't give more information, I'm not sure what info you will need, so if you ask I shall provide. Thanks.

PS: I've been stuck on this for days and have tried what seems to be every thing I can find on Google.

EDIT: As requested, here are the steps I took from the beginning.

I followed this guide step by step: https://www.linode.com/docs/websites/hosting-a-website/

I uploaded my files to /var/www/domain.com/public_html/

I installed fail2ban and followed the firewall step in the "securing your server" guide that is also on Linode. (I cannot post more than 1 link due to lack of reputation)

And then I set up the DNS as stated in the original question.

Comment: Don't make us ask for information. Include everything that might be relevant.

Comment: That's the thing.
I'm not really sure what would be relevant.
I'm pretty new to DNS.

Comment: It's all relevant. Your question as it stands has omitted about 85% of what you actually did. It also doesn't include your domain name or any other pertinent details. Start over and include **everything**. And remember that we are not the NSA so we cannot see what you're doing on your computer.

Comment: I can't include the domain name.

I will post exactly what I did from the beginning in an edit.

Comment: if you think the issue is DNS, running `dig` or `nslookup` from your laptop and from off of your network would help show you what's happening.  You might want to get a box in Digital Ocean or AWS to have an "outside" perspective.

Comment: Everything looks right in dig and nslookup. Someone has mentioned to me that there may be a script somewhere that is redirecting it to https, and then redirects it back to http, thus creating an infinite loop.

Any idea where to look for evidence of that?

I'm sorry I sound like such a noob. I'm trying my best.

Comment: Start by looking in a browser. Any decent browser will have a network tab (normally just hit F12 and look for network). It can probably give a pretty clear hint about what exactly what kind of loop you've created.

Comment: So you redirect by HTTP to http://255.255.255.255 and think you have a DNS problem? You are confusing things. I suggest you start over and to exactly what is written in the linked document.

Comment: That was just an example IP address to show what format I redirected to.
Obviously I'm not going to redirect to 255.255.255.255.
I can't list links to the site in question.

Comment: No, it's not obvious. We get questions from people who do that type of thing on a routine basis. The "redirecting ... in a way that will never complete" error suggests that you need to analyze the output being fed to the web browser; a circular redirect or something similar is happening. Since you have supplied neither the configuration or the domain it is pretty much impossible for us to speculate further. In the absence of experience to troubleshoot this on your own it's necessary to compromise somewhere.

Comment: I'm sorry, I'm a noob with SF and Stack, so...
Well, I solved the problem. It was actually an error in my PHP.